# VBA Macro Printing loop

Tags: vba, excel

[update below]

I have been trying to write a printing macro for my production sheet.

Everything but the actual printouts work great. If I use .Zoom = False instead of .Zoom = 50, the printarea ends up tiny on the printout sheet. If I use zoom=50, I get these inch wide margins to the left and right. What I suspect is that it somehow doesn't process the actual printarea line, but I have no clue why since the other command lines seem to work just fine. I tried to strip the code down to pretty much printarea, fitTopagesxx, and got the same issue.

I tried rewriting the code multiple times now and either get an error prompt or the same results with the other code found on the web.

```
   Sub PrintJob()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Filtered_List")

        For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then Exit For
            With Sheets("Print_Page")
                .Range("C8").Value = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$C$2:$L$60"
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.Zoom = 50
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                Worksheets("Print_Page").PageSetup.FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .PrintOut
            End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

[Update:] I figured out the problem after some help here after finding out it was a sheet specific error. Basically, the print title fields need to be empty and that code that does that is this one:

```
.PrintTitleRows = ""
.PrintTitleColumns = ""
```

I added a few lines more an used the cleaned up code from Noldor130884:

```
Sub PrintJob()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Filtered_List")

        For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then Exit For
            With Worksheets("Print_Page")
            .Range("C8").Value = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
                With .PageSetup
                .PrintArea = "$C$2:$L$60"
                .Orientation = xlPortrait
                .Zoom = False
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = False
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .PrintTitleRows = ""
                .PrintTitleColumns = ""
                .LeftHeader = ""
                .CenterHeader = ""
                .RightHeader = ""
                .LeftFooter = ""
                .CenterFooter = ""
                .RightFooter = ""
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
                .PrintHeadings = False
                .CenterHorizontally = True
                .CenterVertically = False
                .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter

                End With
                .PrintPreview
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hope that saves someone a bit of a headache.

Comment: I would check through the values on the Page Setup dialog box to make sure there 's nothing strange going on e.g. in headers and footers.

Comment: If I print anything else from excel or even the macro/vba area directly by using the ui, it looks perfectly fine. Pretty frustrating.

Comment: Very weird indeed. I don't suppose that adding IgnorePrintAreas:=False would help?... Also I notice that you don't use the With object to set PageSetup values, maybe try using the same way for .PrintOut too? That is, have Worksheets("Print_Page").PrintOut

Comment: I have found out in the meantime that it is sheet specific. If I mark an area on another sheet in the same workbook, open the print setup, and select the option to fit one page, it fits perfectly. When I do the same thing with this sheet, the area ends up super tiny. Do you mind upvoting the question, more people might see it that way? T

Comment: Not sure if that has the effect you might hope for, but upvoted anyway for engagement.

Comment: Finally, I found a solution and will edit my code accordently tomorrow morning. In short, the print title fields need to be empty and that setting is sheet specific. Thanks for working on this one with me, the upvote might have done the trick ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me correct your code a bit:

```
With Worksheets("Print_Page")
    .Range("C8").Value = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$C$2:$L$60"
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Zoom = 50
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    End With
    .PrintOut
End With
```

Now, please notice that [as Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-zoom-property-excel), `Zoom = False` means that *"the FitToPagesWide and FitToPagesTall properties control how the worksheet is scaled."*.

In your code you are using a `Zoom` before those 2 properties, therfore you are overwriting.

If I understood correctly what you want to do, please just remove from your code:

```
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False
```

Comment: I was familiar with the Zoom part but neither setting was working. I edited my original post to reflect the changes needed. I used your cleanded up code, thanks for that.